# What need to use import directive in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx, babeljs

According to [this](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), import statement should be accepted (actually, not, see the comments) by any browser, but when I try to use it, chrome yields about wrong token, syntax error.

This is `react` application.
My html looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>CODETutorial Mean seed</title>
  <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/react/react.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/react-router-dom/index.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root">
    <div id="navbar"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="dist/navbar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in navbar.jsx importing and using Link statements:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

var NavLink = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    return(
      <li className={(this.props.active ? "active" : "")}>
        <Link to={this.props.linkTo}>{this.props.text}</Link>
      </li>
    );
  }
});

...
```

What is wrong with import?

Comment: Actually, according to your link, `import` "is only beginning to be implemented in browsers natively". If you follow the links you'll see that it is not very well supported at all (eg. Chrome supports it only if you enable experimental features).

Comment: Yep, thanks for pointing this. Is there `babel` comand to transpile imports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll still need to use babel, or jump through a few hoops to actually get modules working in your code. If you don't want to use babel, you can follow the guide here: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/08/10/es-modules-node-today/amp/?utm_content=bufferb6a65&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Comment: I use babel as compiler (transpiler): babel src -d dist -w

Comment: It's not a native JavaScript actually, I will have to use babel.